# Can't convert Int to int fo combo

Tags: c#, .net

I have this combobox

```
BindingSource srd = new BindingSource();
srd.DataSource = llenar.Tables["cnae"];
CmbCnaePrin.DataSource = srd;
CmbCnaePrin.DisplayMember = "cnae_descricao";
CmbCnaePrin.ValueMember = "cnae_id";
```

i want to load this

```
int cnaepr;
DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();
dt3 = ifd.cnaeclas(cnaepr);
txtCnaeC.Text = dt3.Rows[0][2].ToString();
txtCnaeSC.Text = dt3.Rows[0][3].ToString();
```

but i can not convert

```
 cnaepr=Convert.ToInt32(CmbCnaePrin.SelectedValue)
```

returns this error Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

Comment: What's with the double-negative? Does that mean that you can in fact convert to int? P.S. [please don't include C# in the titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try calling ToString() on the SelectedValue property:

```
cnaepr=Convert.ToInt32(CmbCnaePrin.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

The error is pretty much exactly what it says; the SelectedValue property is designed to be very generic so it can be anything you could find in a DataTable. Most of those things that it could be are not "convertible" types (implementing IConvertible).

Comment: If `CmbCnaePrin.SelectedValue` is of `DataRowView` type, using `ToString()` method will give You string with `System.Data.DataRowView` value, which is still not valid to be parsed to an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce Your issue with a smaple test application and I can suggest You two possible solutions.

You can remove `BindingSource` object which is in fact only a proxy between `DataTable` and a `ComboBox`.

Applying this solution, the code should look like this:

```
CmbCnaePrin.DataSource = llenar.Tables["cnae"];
CmbCnaePrin.DisplayMember = "cnae_descricao";
CmbCnaePrin.ValueMember = "cnae_id";
```

The rest can be unchanged and you should get an `String` object in `CmbCnaePrin.SelectedValue`.

**Alternative solution (updated)**

Alternatively, You can use BindingSource, but handle `DataRowView` returned in the `CmbCnaePrin.SelectedValue`, as well as cases, when you get the value directly.

Applying this solution, the code should look like this:

```
DataRowView selectedValue = (CmbCnaePrin.SelectedValue as DataRowView);
if (selectedValue != null)
{
    cnaepr = Convert.ToInt32(selectedValue.Row["cnae_id"]);
}
else
{
    cnaepr = Convert.ToInt32(CmbCnaePrin.SelectedValue);
}
```

The rest can be left unchanged.

Let me know if this solves Your issue.

Comment: the first line  works(no error ) , the second not works, continuos the error.

Comment: You wrote that the first solution works, so does is solve your issue? Please note I've also updated the second one, so take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up the combobox DisplayMember and ValueMember before you assign the DataSource.

```
CmbCnaePrin.DisplayMember = "cnae_descricao";
CmbCnaePrin.ValueMember = "cnae_id";
CmbCnaePrin.DataSource = srd;
```

I think assigning those after setting the DataSource means that the combobox is trying to use the default iterator of a DataTable which is a DataRow (or DataRowView on a DataView in this case). So it's setting the ValueMember and the DisplayMember on its own before you assign them.